# Iterate over expanded nodes of QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

I have a `QTreeWidget`. Have to iterate through the nodes which are expanded. Tried with iterating with `QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(<rootNode>, QTreeWidgetItemIterator::NotHidden)`. But it is giving all the nodes of the tree instead of just expanded ones.

Am I missing to set any flag in the iterator?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid there is no specific flag for expanded items (but you can get checked items, for instance, using flags, http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitemiterator.html).

But you can easily check if item is expanded or not while iterating, using [QTreeWidgetItem::isExpanded()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#isExpanded)

Comment: ThanQ.. Ya, did in the same way you mentioned. Just wanted to know if any such flag was there.

Comment: You may accept the answer if it was helpful. There is no specific flag for explanded.

Comment: QTreeWidget::itemBelow(const QTreeWidgetItem * item) served my purpose..